# Universal Image Loader cache images

Tags: android, caching, universal-image-loader

I have trouble finding the right workflow to load images into cache.

What I want to do:

- Show Progress bar
- Get data from REST service and load it into SQLite database
- Some objects contain urls in JSON > load these images in cache so
  they are quickly loaded when needed
- Dismiss Progress bar

I have all the data loaded from rest and stored in a DB,
but I'm new to caching images.

What I go so far:
- Inserted Universal Image Loader into my project
(https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)
- I tried

```
imageLoader.loadImage(url of an image, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                        super.onLoadingStarted(imageUri, view);
                        //notify me the image started loading
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                        super.onLoadingComplete(imageUri, view, loadedImage);
                        //notify me the image is loaded
                    }
}
```

But when I check:

```
int size = MemoryCacheUtils.findCachedBitmapsForImageUri(url from that image, ImageLoader.getInstance().getMemoryCache()).size();
             //show me the size
```

it's always zero.

My question is the following: am I going in the right direction or do I need to fix this someother way?

Comment: what about your manifest? did you put permission writing external storage?

Comment: Yes I did. Internet & Internal Storage

Comment: You should enable caching in memory (in `DisplayImageOptions`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a better solution: ShutterBug (Android alternative for SDWebImage for iOs). It's easy to add urls to the ShutterbugManager and when I want to fill an ImageView (FetchableImageView in Shutterbug) with an image, it grabs the image from cache.